# How to specify dependency across parameters in Param / PyViz

Tags: python, data-visualization, holoviews

I've been working through the excellent tutorial on PyViz (http://pyviz.org/) it covers a lot of what I need. I had one question related to the dashboard example: http://pyviz.org/tutorial/A2_Dashboard_Workflow.html

Specifically where it specifies the Param class to create the widgets.

Is there are way (and are there any good examples that could be shared) to create a parameter that is dependent on one of the other parameters such that if a user selected an option in a drop-down another drop-down can be repopulated based on the value selected in the first one?

Ben

Comment: Yes, it's possible; you would write a method decorated with  `@depends("param1", watch=True)` that updates param2's parameter metadata (range, objects, etc.) when param1 changes.  We do need some examples of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James I'll take a look at those concepts in the Param docs. But obviously an example on Pyviz.org would be fantastic!

Comment: Hi @JamesA.Bednar I found the Google map viewer example in the param docs: https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Param.html but when I run it the country names aren't updating when I change continent. I've rewritten the example for my own requirements, but in that case too, the dependent field does not update

Comment: Do you mean, on that web page, or when you run it  yourself as a notebook? It will only work if you run it yourself, and if there is a problem in that case, please file a github issue.  [ETA: Actually, an issue just appeared: https://github.com/pyviz/panel/issues/300]

Comment: Hi @JamesA.Bednar - issue was on a notebook I was running locally

Comment: Should be fixed in current Panel master; see https://github.com/pyviz/panel/issues/300